# Google Spreadsheet Functionality integrated with the HUD?

Tags: hud

I use google spreadsheets a lot. If I could find a way to use google spreadsheets with Ubuntu's HUD, I would be a lot more productive. Say for example, if I could access the command "Merge Cells Horizontally" through the hud, this would improve my workflow manifold.

I am looking for **ANY** solutions, regardless of how hacky it is.

Comment: It's part of google docs right? looks like it might have had this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature can't seem to get it working now...